# Sql: Check if a column is used in another table

Tags: sql

I have the following scenario: I have two table, genres and movies. Genres has id and title column, Movies table has id,title,release date,price,rating and genreId as FK. 
The FK is reading the Id from the genre table.

My use case is the following. If I create a new genre, Action for example, and afterwards create two new movies with this genre, I shouldn't be able to delete the genre since it's used by two movies.

I need some help with the SQL syntax.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. But in general: just create a foreign key constraint

Comment: Check the FK constraint documentation. (on delete ...)

Comment: As you already have genreId as FK then the deletion would not happen as it would throw an exception stating child records found.